# How to implement Java's @StringDef in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, annotations, lint

I need a Java `@StringDef` Annotation for my Kotlin project.

Unfortunately this seems difficult. I found that discussion here:

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/intdef-and-stringdef-not-being-checked-at-compile-time/7029/3

where I understood it's probably a Lint issue. No compile time checks are done. Neither suggestions made. I can just add any String as parameter.

I ended up creating a Java class with just my constants.

```
public class AppFeatures {

    /** @hide */
    @StringDef({USER, USER_ACCOUNT})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface AppFeature {}

    /** Constants for certain features */
    public static final String USER = "user";
    public static final String USER_ACCOUNT = "user.account";
}
```

When using the Kotlin equivalent there are no compile time checks nor suggestions.

I tried something like this but with no success:

```
@StringDef(USER, USER_ACCOUNT)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class AppFeature

const val USER = "user"
const val USER_ACCOUNT = "user.account"
```

**So how can I implement this in Kotlin?**

Comment: Apparently @StringDef is an Android annotation that provides enum-like String-based typing.  Details here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringDef

Comment: I know. It just doesn't like Kotlin (& Lint)

Answer (score 1):

@StringDef now works if you define it inside a companion object.  For example:

```
public class Test {

    companion object {

         @StringDef(SLOW, NORMAL, FAST)
         @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
         annotation class Speed

         const val SLOW = "slow"
         const val NORMAL = "normal"
         const val FAST = "fast"
    }

    @Speed
    private lateinit var speed: String

    public fun setSpeed(@Speed speed: String) {
        this.speed = speed
    }
}
```

This code sample is mostly cribbed (with very minor changes) from:
https://newbedev.com/how-to-use-android-support-typedef-annotations-in-kotlin

Please also consider using a Kotlin enum class instead, which will allow you to specify the String value for each enum:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html

Enums are a memory problem for phones running with Dalvik, but that’s basically been discontinued in place of the ART (Android Runtime Machine). Added to the fact that even people in poorer countries have fairly powerful phones, and that Proguard can now optimize code better than ever, it’s safe to say that Enums no longer cause a problem in performance. More about this here:
https://www.ericthecoder.com/2019/10/07/kotlin-or-java-enum-classes-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/