# Define StringDef in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I'm trying to define a StringDef in kotlin:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@StringDef(NORTH, SOUTH)
annotation class FilterType {

    companion object {
        const val NORTH = "NORTH"
        const val SOUTH = "SOUTH"
    }
}
```

I think something is wrong in the code above.

```
// I can send anything to this method, when using my kotlin stringDef
private fun takeString(@DirectionJava.Direction filterType: String) {
```

I want the kotlin equivalent of the java below:

```
public class DirectionJava {

    public static final String NORTH = "NORTH";
    public static final String SOUTH = "SOUTH";

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({
            NORTH,
            SOUTH,
    })
    public @interface Direction {

    }
}
```

Calling the java defined StringDef works from kotlin

```
// This works as expected, the Java-written string def 
// restricts what I can pass to this method
private fun takeString(@DirectionJava.Direction filterType: String) {
```

Where have I gone wrong, how do you define a StringDef in Kotlin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATED: Sep 19, 2023**

Now Lint is checking enumerated annotations like `IntDef`, `StringDef`, *etc* and gives you a compile-time error if the value is not compliant.

[image]

```
companion object {
    const val NORTH = 1
    const val SOUTH = 2
    const val WEST = 3
    const val EAST = 4
}

@IntDef(NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class Direction

@Direction
private var direction: Int = NORTH
```

---

According to [jetbrains issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7729), `Lint` check plugin for enumerated annotations in kotlin is under development and is not stable yet. Checking android support annotations such as `@Nullable`, `@StringRes`, `@DrawableRes`, `@IntRange`, ... (which are written in java) works fine and user defined enumerated annotations are not checked properly. So, it seems that we should define them in java then use in kotlin.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no evidence of improvement on this topic in Kotlin. So the lint doesn't check the value of variables for annotated user-defined StringDef, and etc.

Comment: Could you please update your answer? See below answer.

Answer (score 2):

@StringDef now works if you define it inside a companion object.  See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70672074/2465264

Also, consider using a Kotlin enum class instead since the performance issues have been fixed in ART (Android Runtime Machine), which most Android devices are now running.